# Compiling Qt5.2.1 from source on windows

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, mingw

I downloaded the `qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw48_opengl-5.2.1.exe`

installed also the source.

Compiling MinGW:

- `cd C:\QtSDK\5.2.1\Src\qtbase\qmake`
- `make`
- Return: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`

In that folder is the correct one for copilar `Qt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not the correct folder.

You have to run `configure` from the root of the source directory.  This will generate the necessary Makefiles.  Then you execute `make`.  Detailed instructions are available on the Qt project website:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-building.html

Be warned, the Qt build is quite lengthy.

Comment: It is not simply lengthy, it is very very tricky requiring multiple 3rd party languages (python, rupy, perl if you want webkit). In comparison, compiling Qt4 was a breezy walk in the park.

Comment: @esorton `./configure -platform ?` the `-platform` I use that command? Compiling for windows(MinGW). `./configure -planform win32-msvc return system/compiler is not supported`